# Как программно задействовать второе ядро?

Tags: delphi

У меня есть прога (написанная на Delphi 7) которая "колбасит" структурированный текстовый файл.

Внимание вопрос: как программно задействовать в моей обработке второе ядро процессора? Т.к. очень хочется сократить время обработки как минимум в двое!

P.S.: так же приму либы советы по настройке компилятора, ссылки на статьи и прочее по оптимизации быстродействия кода реализованного в Delphi 7.

Comment: Нужно разбивать задачу на два потока. А иначе никак.
Но сократить вдвое вряд ли получится, а вот в полтора раза - легко.

Comment: Даже в 1.5 - было бы очень даже хорошо! 

Два потока? Хм.. А можно пример на пальцах?

Comment: нужно лучше знать Вашу задачу. Может быть ее и нельзя распараллелить.

Comment: А чем это определяется? Я например не могу на представить как можно распараллелить ряд последовательных действий.

Comment: Нужно смотреть на код.

Comment: Интересно, какого же размера этот текстовый файл и **что** Вы с ним делаете, если **надо сократить время обработки как минимум в двое!".**

Comment: @saipress, любой нагружающий цикл можно просто запускать в несколько потоков. Если, например, у вас обработка массива - можно передавать в поток указатель на массив, номер потока и кол-во записей (`Addr(mas), 0, 250` на 4 потока при 1000 записей)

Comment: Ну весь код суда вывалить не возможно, да и потом пояснять всю ньансы тоже.. 
Если забить на многопоточность, как ещё можно увеличить скорость работы приложения?

Comment: Написать более эффективный код. Например, вместо пузырьковой сортировки использовать quick sort, вместо циклов вида s := s+' '; заведомо сразу выделять память.

Comment: Если вы имеете дело со структурированным файлом, то можно раздать по потокам №№ 1, 2,... обработку структур №№ 1, 2,..., а потом все результаты вывалить в интерфейсный (основной) поток. Как-то так, по-моему.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Создание потока: 
Delphi - File - New - Other - Delphi Files - Thread Object

*тут был старый ответ*

**UPD**

Описание работы с потоками в Delphi [ТУТ](http://prodelphi.ucoz.ru/publ/rabota_s_potokami_v_delphi/1-1-0-16)

Comment: Пятая кнопка в редакторе оформляет код.

Comment: Зачем так длинно-то? Написали такой длинный код, а могли просто сказать, что здесь потоки в помощь...но все равно, я плюсую =)

Comment: ну может, человек не знает, как создавать потоки?)  
а я "вкратце" объяснил, что да как)

Comment: Это ужасный пример для работы с потоками. Почитайте, что делает метод Synchronize и узнайте, что если запустить два таких потока (пусть даже они разные  формы изменяют и визуально не мешают друг дружке), то производительность программы скорее даже будет ниже, чем если это было бы сделано без потоков.
О конструкциях вида `Form13.Visible= true` и `until true;` я молчу. Таймер, который запускает тред...

Comment: полностью согласен :)  
но это давнешнее сообщение, которое отражает еще более давнюю работу с потоками, когда я только начинал изучать делфи :)  
кстати, раз уж пошла такая пьянка, то обновлю ответ.

Comment: Правда, надо понимать, что если ядер меньше, чем потоков, то это ничего не даст.

Comment: @Asen надо понимать принцип работы процессора, и что дополнительный поток - это дополнительное процессорное время, и что результат все равно будет.  
А еще надо вопрос читать, в котором пользователь ясно дал понять, что у него два ядра. Хотя даже если бы у него было 10 ядер, то все равно количество потоков, которые ежемоментно обрабатываются процессором будет больше количества ядер. Так что же нам теперь, совсем перестать потоки юзать?

Comment: @Asen Надо понимать, что случай, когда ядер меньше, чем потоков, все еще дает возможность асинхронно выполнить какую-то операцию в другом потоке, не затрагивая работу основного *(например, `GUI'`шного).*