# Как выполнить SQL-запрос в несколько потоков?

Tags: delphi, interbase, firebird, sql

**БД Firebird/Interbase**.

Суть проблемы такая: имеется таблица (например, `MainTable`) с первичным ключем `ID`, также содержит поля `DAT` тип `DateStamp`, `IND` тип `VARCHAR(6)`. Таблица с большим набором данных порядка 2,5 млн. записей и более. Есть четыре SQL запроса:

```
1) select * from MainTable where DAT=:DAT and (not IND is null)
2) select IND from MainTable where not(IND is null) and DAT=:DAT GROUP BY IND
3) select * from MainTable where DAT=:DAT and IND=:IND
4) select distinct DAT from MainTable where not (DAT is null)
```

Самые "долгоиграющие" 1,3,4, выполняются порядка 1,5 минуты. Есть мысль в приложении (на Delphi) распределить выполнение запроса на потоки, вот только как ума не приложу.
Может, кто подскажет, как еще можно оптимизировать выполнение запросов?

Использую компоненты IBX.

Есть задумка выбирать по отдельному блоку данных на поток, т.е. выбирать в каждом потоке по блоку записей, скажем, по 1000: `select first :k skip :n * from MainTable`, выберет k записей, начиная с n-ой не включительно.

Comment: "выполняются 1.5 минуты"... если уж они такие долгоиграющие, то ИМХО, даже если и получится каким-то образом их разбить, то будет грузиться ЦП и, вряд ли, получиться сделать прирост производительности.
мб я и не прав =/

Answer (score 2):

Создание потоков [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60128/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE), хотя не знаю, в принципе, чем тебе помочь. Задача сама по себе странная - каждый запрос в несколько потоков... =/

Изучаем [это](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D2%F0%E0%ED%E7%E0%EA%F6%E8%FF) и все, тому подобное.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать ADO-компоненты, там в свойствах `ExecuteOptions` есть параметр `eoAsyncExecute`. Только после это придёться аккуратно следить за завершениями запросов.

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но разве этот параметр отвечает не за асинхронное выполнение запроса? Приложение то конечно висеть не будет, но вот наврядли запрос пройдет быстрее.

Comment: Как я понял задача была именно выполнить 4 запроса в одно время, в данном случае асинхронность как раз поможет

Comment: Не тут я просто описал какие запросы вообще в утилите используются, нужно чтоб SQL запрос каждый выполнялся в несколько потоков.

Answer (score 1):

От того, что вы сделаете несколько потоков в клиенте ничего не изменится. Все равно все выполняется на стороне сервака. Другое дело если бы стояла задача синхронизации ответов сервера на клиенте - тогда разбиение на несколько потоков с последующим `Thread.join()` помогло бы.

А так лучше составить план запроса `explain plan` в Oracle или засунув запрос SQL Studio посмотреть на Execution Plan и соптимизировать запрос, написать индексы и проч.